# How to summarize date data by groups in R

Tags: r, summary, tapply, group-summaries

I would like to summarize the following sample data into a new dataframe as follows:

Population, Sample Size (N), Percent Completed (%)

Sample Size is a count of all records for each population. I can do this using the table command or tapply. Percent completed is the percentage of records with 'End Date's (all records without 'End Date' are assumed to not complete. This is where I am lost!

**Sample Data**

```
 sample <- structure(list(Population = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Glommen", 
    "Kaseberga", "Steninge"), class = "factor"), Start_Date = structure(c(16032, 
    16032, 16032, 16032, 16032, 16036, 16036, 16036, 16037, 16038, 
    16038, 16039, 16039, 16039, 16039, 16039, 16039, 16041, 16041, 
    16041, 16041, 16041, 16041, 16044, 16044, 16045, 16045, 16045, 
    16045, 16048, 16048, 16048, 16048, 16048, 16048), class = "Date"), 
        End_Date = structure(c(NA, 16037, NA, NA, 16036, 16043, 16040, 
        16041, 16042, 16042, 16042, 16043, 16043, 16043, 16043, 16043, 
        16043, 16045, 16045, 16045, 16045, 16045, NA, 16048, 16048, 
        16049, 16049, NA, NA, 16052, 16052, 16052, 16052, 16052, 
        16052), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Population", "Start_Date", 
    "End_Date"), row.names = c(NA, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with split/apply/combine:

```
spl = split(sample, sample$Population)
new.rows = lapply(spl, function(x) data.frame(Population=x$Population[1],
                                              SampleSize=nrow(x),
                                              PctComplete=sum(!is.na(x$End_Date))/nrow(x)))
combined = do.call(rbind, new.rows)
combined

#           Population SampleSize PctComplete
# Glommen      Glommen         13   0.6923077
# Kaseberga  Kaseberga          7   1.0000000
# Steninge    Steninge         15   0.8666667
```

One word of warning: `sample` is the name of a base function, so you should pick a different name for your data frame.

Comment: Sorry about the dataframe name. I was trying to keep in simple. I appreciate the solution using the base functions. I had a more complicated problem and your solution helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(sample, .(Population), summarize, 
      Sample_Size = length(End_Date),
      Percent_Completed = mean(!is.na(End_Date)) * 100)

#   Population Sample_Size Percent_Completed
# 1    Glommen          13          69.23077
# 2  Kaseberga           7         100.00000
# 3   Steninge          15          86.66667
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. I only voted for the split/apply/combine solution as I like to learn R with the base packages. Thank you!